# BleachBit: How to Completely Clear URL History in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, history, privacy

14.04 / Firefox 29.0

I've been using [Bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download) to clear usage/file history, and for the most part it works great.  However, it doesn't seem to clear the website hostnames out of the URL, at all.  These addresses are not bookmarked.  Also, the total URL isn't preserved, just the hostname.

1. Visit site http://www.bluesnews.com/some_random_URL_string
2. Exit Firefox
3. Run Bleachbit, with ALL Firefox options selected
4. Restart Firefox
5. Check history: completely empty, other than bookmarked sites. www.bluesnews is NOT bookmarked
6. Type "blue" which is Firefox automatically completes as "http://www.bluesnews.com/"

Alternate Step #3: Use Firefox's built-in "Clear History" and select ALL entries with a time frame of "Everything".  Same result as above.

My inquiry in BB forums hasn't been responded to.  I found [Dan's](https://askubuntu.com/a/276843/283892) proposed solution, however changing `autocomplete` in `about:config` only turns off the function, it doesn't actually stop storing URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite extreme, but you could delete the `.mozilla` or `.mozilla/Firefox folder`. Unfortunately, every time you open firefox, it will bring up the import dialogue. This may be able to be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I actually found a less extreme way to solve this. 
1. Exit Firefox
2. Navigate to `.mozilla/firefox/xxxxx.default/`
3. Delete the file `places.sqlite`
4. Restart Firefox -> Previous URLs no longer complete.

I'm not sure what else **places.sqlite** may have dominion over, but so far so good.  Thanks for pointing me in a good direction!

Comment: For anyone else using BleachBit, open the app...
1. Click **Edit / Preferences / Custom**
2. Click **Add file** and enter `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxx.default/places.sqlite`.  Close the Preferences box.
3. In the _left column_ of BleachBit's window, place a check next to **System / Custom**.
4. Run the app at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In the address bar type: `about:config`, when the warning message appears, click on "I'll be careful, I promise!".

Search for newtab, and change `browser.newtabpage.enabled` to false, and for `browser.newtab.url`, double-click it and change to `about:blank`.

[image]

Comment: I get what changing `browser.newtab.url` to **about:blank** does; but I'm unsure what `browser.newtabpage.enabled` to **false** does.  I'm also not sure how it pertains to my original question.  It also doesn't seem to have fixed what I was after. :)