# Cannot remove website from the address bar suggestions

Tags: keyboard, firefox

There is a URL saved in my browser which is really annoying, because it prevents me from autocomplete another URL that I visit far more often.

According to this [docs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-websites-address-bar-suggestions#w_clearing-a-single-item-from-the-address-bar-history) one only has to click on the suggestion, and then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to remove it. This would help so much.

However, when I press <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd>, nothing happens. I have a German keyboard, this is what I press:

[image]

I also found a question from 2013 [How to remove typed-in URLs from browser history in Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276839/how-to-remove-typed-in-urls-from-browser-history-in-firefox) but the links in the answer don't work, and installing an SQLiteManager seems maybe not the best solution in 2019 to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Strg</kbd> is *not* same as the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, <kbd>Strg</kbd> is equivalent to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (control) key in a standard English keyboard.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> is the *key above* <kbd>Strg</kbd> (marked with an upwards arrow) [in your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdw0I.png).

Comment: Whoups, yes I marked and said the wrong key. But it is still not working. I tried it with shift+delete,, ctrl+delete and alt+delete

Comment: Hmm... cannot reproduce, works fine for me (only Shift+Del, none of the others). What is your Ubuntu version and desktop environment and Firefox version?

Comment: Also did you correctly understand the "Clearing a single item from the address bar history" part  from the docs page you included in the question? It just teaches how to remove a website from the address bar *suggestions* (the ones you see after clicking the down arrow in the address bar), *not* from the *auto-complete suggestions*. For that you need to remove the item from your history.

Comment: @Adam In `Preferences > Privacy & Security` is an `Adressbar` section where you can choose what to use as suggestions in the addressbar, maybe you should adjust this settings to your need as well.

Comment: I had in `Preferences` still `Bookmarks` on. I unchecked, because the website was actually a bookmark, now I could remove it (however, it does not work with mouse  hovering, I need to go down with keyboard keys).